# Difference between IAG and IDM

Tags: terminology, identity-management, governance

What is the difference between Identity Management products (such as Forefront/MIM, PicketLink, OpenIDM) and Identity Access Governance tools (such as Sailpoint,Savyint, CyberArk)?

Apologies for another one of these terminology questions, I did look at the '[what is IAM](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/187426/how-to-get-better-iam-understanding/187501#187501)' question but it seems to be broader and the response doesn't mention IM/IDM as a separate component and also separates PAM and IAG which I thought are part of the same solution.